# python, find and print specific cells in csv files that are in different directories

Tags: python, csv

I have different csv files in different directories. so i want to find specific cells in different columns that correspond to a specific date in my input.txt file.
here is what i have until now:

```
import glob, os, csv, numpy
import re, csv

if __name__ == '__main__':
Input=open('Input.txt','r');
output = []
for i, line in enumerate(Input):
    if i==0:
       header_Input = Input.readline().replace('\n','').split(',');
    else:
       date_input = Input.readline().replace('\n','').split(',');
a=os.walk("path to the directory")
[x[0] for x in os.walk("path to the directory")]
print(a)
b=next(os.walk('.'))[1] # immediate child directories.
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    # print path to all subdirectories first.
    for subdirname in dirnames:
      print(os.path.join(dirname, subdirname))

     # print path to all filenames.
    for filename in filenames:
      #print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
      csvfile = 'csv_file'
      if csvfile in filename:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
```

Now I have the csv files, so i need to find the date_input in every file, and print the line that contains all the information. Or if possible, to get only the cells that are in the columns with header == header_input.

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended to be a full answer to your question. But you may want to consider replacing

```
for i, line in enumerate(Input):
    if i==0:
       header_Input = Input.readline().replace('\n','').split(',');
    else:
       date_input = Input.readline().replace('\n','').split(',');
```

with

```
header_Input = Input.readline().strip().split(',')
date_input = Input.readline().strip().split(',')
```

The `enumerate(Input)` expression reads lines from the file, and so do calls to `readline()` in the loop body. This will most likely result in some unfortunate results like reading alternating lines from the file.

The `strip()` method removes whitespace from the start and end of the line. Alternatively you may want to know that `s[:-1]` strips off the last character of `s`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!